# How can I pass the small and large jsonPayload more efficiently?

Tags: c#, json, api, testing, httpwebresponse

Currently I am testing rest APIs E2E and I am passing the Json payload as a string like this
I also created a Model to hold different payloads but HTTPWebResponse can not convert to string. Any ideas how can I pass these JSonPayload and also Large payloads for efficiently

```
 public HttpWebResponse UpdateEndpointsFromTags(int id, int parent_id)
        {
            RequestHandler requestor = new RequestHandler(BaseUrl + "UpdateEndpointsFromTags", HttpVerb.POST, AuthenticationType.Bearer);
            var requestJSON = "[ { \"id\": " + id + ", \"parentId\": " + parent_id + " } ]";
            var response = requestor.SendRequest(requestJSON);
            return response;
        }
```

Comment: "I also created a Model to hold different payloads but HTTPWebResponse can not convert to string" -- you need to `serialize` your objects to JSON. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to

Comment: I did when you serialize like so it returns in a string. I can do this when my function methods are HttpWebresponse                                            
 var json = tags.GetTagById(input_tag_id);
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            ModelTag[] tag = js.Deserialize<ModelTag[]>(json);